# count the number of property in object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Am trying to find the count of **isSelected= true** form the given object.

```
   {
    "MainData1": [
        {
            "Child1": [
                {
                    "value": "item1",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "item2",
                    "isSelected": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "MainData2": [
        {
            "Child2": [
                {
                    "value": "item",
                    "isSelected": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i Was tried **forEach** loop.

can we do it in a simple way?

The expected count will be **3**

Note: It is a dynamic data

Thanks in advance

Comment: "MainData" is not a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all the unknown keys you can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to retrieve corresponding values and then use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get count for each object. Outer [`array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can be used to count all nested filtered arrays:

```js
const data = {
    "MainData1": [
        {
            "Child1": [
                {
                    "value": "item1",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "item2",
                    "isSelected": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "MainData2": [
        {
            "Child2": [
                {
                    "value": "item",
                    "isSelected": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

const count = Object.values(data).flatMap(x => x).reduce(
   (count, current) => count + Object.values(current).flatMap(x => x).filter(x => x.isSelected).length, 0);

console.log(count);
```

Comment: how to handle if we have MainData1 and MainData2 is present

Comment: @arj use another `Object.values`, modified my answer

Comment: Cmon @arj you gotta be able to do some things yourself... mickl has given you a great start you just need to tweak it accordingly. Saw now that he was kind enough to help you, hope you compensate him

Comment: Thanks all.Am appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 0):

I think the line of code, should being like this

```js
const data = {
    "MianData": [
        {
            "Child1": [
                {
                    "value": "item1",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "item2",
                    "isSelected": true
                }
               
            ],
            "Child2": [
                {
                    "value": "item3",
                    "isSelected": true
                },
                {
                    "value": "item4",
                    "isSelected": false
                }
               
            ]
        }
    ]
}

let result = 0;

if (data.MianData.Child1[0].isSelected){
result++;
}
if (data.MianData.Child1[1].isSelected){
result++;
}
if (data.MianData.Child2[0].isSelected){
result++;
}
if (data.MianData.Child2[1].isSelected){
result++;
}

console.log(result);
//or
return result;
```

Hope it should be helpful for you.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried this? I get Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement as you are trying to return outside the scope of a function and it doesnt correctly select the objects as you havent taken into account that MianData is an array. Also you may want to consider a approach where the code handles if the list with data gets larger over time.

Comment: Unfortunately, i online via mobile device now. Will evaluate my solution soon. I'm apologize for the error

Comment: No need to apologize, just found some issues i wanted to give feedback on. Not a big deal!